# Display emails related to a custom field in the activity email widget of the contact

Tags: email, widget

By default, Salesforce displays all emails related to a contact (via the standard email field) in the activity email widet.

[image]

For a business case, a contact can have up to 3 email addresses, so 2 custom fields more.

Is there a way to display all emails related to the three email addresses of the contact in the activity email widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this through the native Salesforce `Activity History`. You will need to write a custom Lightning Component that recreates the native `Activity History` and not just queries on the standard `Email` field but also the two custom email fields.

A custom `Activity History` Lightning Component would be pretty complex project if wanted to match closely the native style, so I'd suggest only pursuing if imperative to day-to-day operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you sending email using apex code, this is possible. You need to set TargetObjectId for Messaging.SingleEmailMessage record as below:

mail.setToAddresses(new List{ con.custom email field });
mail.setTargetObjectId(con.Id);
mail.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);

Hope this helps.